# How to find smallest angle of rotation between two polygons

Tags: geometry, optimization, maxima-minima, polygons

I have two polygons (e.g. two triangles) with mutual centre and I need to reconcile these polygons so that the sum of squares of distances between the vertices of one polygon and the other is minimal

I tried to do this by minimizing the sum of the squared distances of all combinations of vertices of two polygons using the polar coordinate system but it's not work

Distance in square between two points in polar coordinates is:

$$\rho_{1}^{2}\rho_{2}^{2}-2\rho_{1}\rho_{2}cos(\phi_{1}-\phi_{2})$$

Hence sum in square is $\phi$ is angle of the rotation second polygon):

$$\sum_{i,j}(\rho_{i}^{2}\rho_{j}^{2}-2\rho_{i}\rho_{j}\cos(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j}-\phi))\rightarrow min$$

Then (e.g. using golden-section search) I find unknow angle

For example:

Two triangles:
Coordinates in polar sistem

First - (1;0), (1;135), (1,225)

Second - (1,45), (1;180), (1;315)

Sum of squares is:

9 - 2cos(0-45-x)-2cos(0-180-x)-2cos(0-315-x)-2cos(135-45-x)-2cos(135-180-x)-2cos(135-315-x)-2cos(225-45-x)-2cos(225-180-x)-2cos(225-315-x)

...golden-section...(a,b = -$\pi$,$\pi$)

Angle is -119.44...

But angle must be 180 (or -180)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Please use [MathJax notation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of images. The question itself sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply rotate the second triangle 45 degrees clockwise, it appears that the first two point sets will coincide and the third point sets will be only 45 degrees away from each other. Another 45 degrees would make the 3rd points coincide but then the first two would be off by 45 degrees each as they are now. I think the simplest solution is a single 45 degree rotation.

Comment: But how to find it mathematically?

Comment: And the closest points will be if you rotate first (or second triangle) 180 degrees

Comment: The previous comment is correct. Rotating the second triangle 180 will make all three vertices match those of the first triangle.